# Segmentation fault when trying to assign int to object

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to assign an int value to an object property. When I do so, a segmentation fault occurs.

Instead of trying to assign it to a public property right away, I created a setter function, but this also just leads to a segmentation fault.

```
void list_item::set_value_1(int value)
{
     this->value_1 = value;
}
```

...

```
void list::add(int value1, int value2)
{
list_item* insert_item = new list_item;
insert_item->next = nullptr;
insert_item = this->tail;

this->tail = new list_item;
this->tail = this->tail->next;

insert_item->set_value_1(value1);
insert_item->set_value_2(value2);
this->size++;
}
```

The exact error message is `Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)` and it does occur on the very line the value should be set.

Comment: I would guess, the `this` pointer isn't initialized and/or null.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @OlafDietsche. How do I initialize the ``this`` pointer? I alwyas though that it would be automatically created as soon as I initialize a new instance of a class. Also that doesn't really explain why I also can't directly write the value if I make ``value1`` a public property.

Comment: @c64forthewin the error you are getting can happen if you call the method on a NULL or invalid pointer. Example `list* l; //no initialization of the variable l->add(1, 2); //call a method on an "unvalid" pointer - UB, often a segmentation fault`

Comment: @c64forthewin When the pointer isn't initialized/null, it makes no difference if you set the value directly or through a method.

Comment: @GianPaolo I understand, but I thought I initialized the object at line 3 of the second code block with ``ist_item* insert_item = new list_item;``. Isn't this an initialization? Sorry, I am very new to c++, but I thought that's how you reserve memory dynamically.

Comment: Depending on the platform, there are tools that can help you debug those crashes. For example, Linux has valgrind. In gcc and Clang, you can enable address sanitizers, which is very useful during development.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I initialized `insert_item` as a new instance of `list_item`, but overwrote it with `this->tail`, which, however, was a nullpointer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess

```
void list::add(int value1, int value2)
{
list_item* insert_item = new list_item;
insert_item->next = nullptr;
insert_item = this->tail; // <- this looks suspicious

this->tail = new list_item; // <- this one too
this->tail = this->tail->next;

insert_item->set_value_1(value1);
insert_item->set_value_2(value2);
this->size++;
}
```

The combination of

```
insert_item = this->tail; // <- this looks suspicious
// ...
insert_item->set_value_1(value1);
```

causes the segmentation fault. Maybe the member `list::tail` isn't initialized at this point.